# Clear form values after submission ajax in global server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

This is my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="myForm" method="POST" action="http://abcd.xyz/server/post.php">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class=" col-sm-2 " for="name">NAME:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 ">
                    <input type="name" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="Enter name" required="name" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class=" col-sm-2 " for="number">EXPENSIVE:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 ">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="exp" placeholder="Enter Number" required="number" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 " for="date">DATE:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 ">
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" placeholder="Enter date" required="date" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comment" class="col-sm-2 ">COMMENTS:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 ">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="comment" placeholder="Enter Comments" required="text" ></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 ">
                    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-default" >Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

The following is the ajax markup for processing my form:

```
$('form.form-horizontal').on('submit',function(){
var that =$(this),
url = that.attr('action'),
type = that.attr('method'),
data = {};

that.find('[name]').each(function(index,value){
    var that = $(this),
    name = that.attr('name'),
    value = that.val();

    data[name] = value;
});
$.form-horizontal({
    url:"http://abcd.xyz/server/post.php",
    type: type,
    data: data,
    success: function(response){
     console.log(response);
     $('form.form-horizontal')[0].reset();//   
    }
});
return false; });
```

The above ajax code is not working on global server, but it is on a local server.

This is the changed version of the `success` part of my script:

```
success: function(response){
     console.log(response);
     $('form.ajax')[0].reset();//.1  
      $('form.ajax').val("");//  .2
     $('.ajax').val("");//       .3
    }
```

I tried both, but I still can't clear my form.

Comment: 2 class attributes on one form tag?, also, your ajax might just nog get in the success callback

Comment: Where are you defining `that`? Do you see any errors in your console? Is this even using ajax, or is it doing a full page post?

Comment: now look at my code . i defined that and removed the one class .,but still my  form is not return to empty value?

Comment: Uhm, no, you still have 2 class attributes on your form tag

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the ajax request is not cross domain.`http://abcd.xyz` is your server address?

Comment: For general I informed abcd.xyz as my server address.,but abcd.xyz is not my real server address :P

Comment: yes it showing  Uncaught ReferenceError: horizontal is not defined ??

Comment: change `$.form-horizontal` to `$('form.form-horizontal')` and try again

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function

Comment: ok,add a <script> element with a src attribute pointing to a jquery file at first